# ios - Segue between two table views sqlite

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, uitableview

I have the following tables

Bike Brands (Parent):

```
      id | brand
---------------------
       1  |  Trek
       2  |  Salsa
```

Bike Models (Child)

```
      id  |    model        | brandid
------------------------------------------
       1  |  Superfly FS    | 1
       2  |  Vaya 3         | 2
       3  |  Superfly 9 SL  | 1
       4  |  Vaya 7         | 2
```

I have two UITableViewController. I want to pass from one tableview to another and to show only bikes from the chosen brand.

To pass data from one tableview to another need to use prepareForSegue?

I tried different queries inner join to show bikes from chosen brand but I cant find one that is working.

""ex: What I want is when choose brand for EX Trek to show all models for this brand in another tableview

Comment: is brandid and id are the same? what is the foreign key here?

Comment: @T_77 yes brandid is the same of id (bike brands table)

Comment: pablio, yes, you generally use `prepareForSegue` for this. In terms of why it's not working, you first should confirm that the `brandid` was successfully received by the destination view controller. You have to narrow down the problem, confirming whether the problem is the passing of the `brandid` or some error in the query in the destination view controller. Once you've narrowed down the problem, if you're still having problems, include the relevant code sample. We can't tell you what the problem is without [seeing the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

let's you have one tableview on screen with brand detail like brand name and id.

when user click on any brand then pass that brand's id in next view controller.

now in second view controller in viewDidAppear call method to retrive data who has the same brand id that you selected in previous controller.

here is the query

**Query** : select * from Bike Models where brandid=(selected brand id in previous controller)

this will return array contains all bikes data who match above query.

and then just reload you table view.

Hope this will help you.